# Is there anyway we can add arrows to support visibility for more li nav-items in the small screen for Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

```js
subComponents: any = [
    { label: 'test1', path: 'test1' },
    { label: 'test2', path: 'test1' },
    { label: 'test3', path: 'test3' },
    { label: 'test4', path: 'test4' },
    { label: 'test4', path: 'settings' },
    { label: 'test5', path: 'test5' },
    { label: 'test6', path: 'test6' },
    { label: 'test7', path: 'test7' },
    { label: 'test8', path: 'test8' },
    { label: 'test9', path: 'test9' },
    { label: 'test10', path: 'test10' }
  ];
```

```html
<ul id="demoTabs" class="nav" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let tab of subComponents">
    <span [textContent]="tab.label"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am looking for a solution to add navigation arrows to my li navigation loop which will work if the **screen size is smaller** for a larger screen if all tabs are visible then hide the arrows.

Is there any way I can achieve something like this?

Below is my stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarit-tabs-with-router-static-6ruaac

[image]

Comment: UINavigationBar is specific to iOS. Are you asking about iOS, or are you asking about web technologies in general, like your other tags indicate?

Comment: Also, please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on stackblitz. See [ask], where it says "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**."